# export function inside react component or access state in same file outside of component

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that needs to be exported from the file, but at the same time, I need to utilize react state to re-render when updated.

It doesn't quite seem like it possible to export a function from inside of the class, so how can I update state from a function outside of the class?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export function functionName(){
const filter = some filter;
  this.setState({
    filter: newFilter
  })
}

class ClassName extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      filter: {}
    }
  }
  render(){
    <>
    </>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can export `functionName` to the outside, but you won't have an access to `this.setState` inside that function.

So you might want to make it `pure`, return a new state.
Refer to this tip by Dan Abramov - https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/824308413559668744?lang=en

So let's do something fun by making that `functionName` reusable by following Dan's tip.

---

*You can follow along with a working demo below.*
[image: Edit so.answer.57417643]

---

In the code below, `increment` & `decrement` matches to `functionName` from your post. A function to update the state (but actually returns a new state).

`Counter` matches your `ClassName`, within which, you want to re-use the function you are exporting.

The way to re-use the exported functions is by calling `this.setState` within `Counter` (refer to `handleIncrement/handleDecrement`).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

// https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/824308413559668744/photo/1
export const increment = (state, props) => ({
  value: state.value + 1
});
export const decrement = (state, props) => ({
  value: state.value - 1
});

class Counter extends Component {
  state = { value: 0 };

  handleIncrement = () => this.setState(increment);
  handleDecrement = () => this.setState(decrement);

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <h1>Counter.jsx: {value}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleDecrement}>-</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Now `Counter`, `increment`, and `decrement` are exported and can be imported elsewhere.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Counter, { increment, decrement } from "./Counter";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState({ value: 0 });

  //                      ... Being reused! 
  const handleIncrement = () => setCount(increment);
  const handleDecrement = () => setCount(decrement);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <section>
        <h1>App: {count.value}</h1>
        <button onClick={handleIncrement}>+</button>
        <button onClick={handleDecrement}>-</button>
      </section>

      <section>
       {/*  We can use the counter as it is */}
        <Counter />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can import it in another file, and use `Counter` to use as it is, or re-use `increment/decrement` inside a Function Component as well.

That means, you can use the same logic in both Class AND Function Components!

[image: demo]

Answer (score -1):

You can add the function inside you component and export the component using the 
   following syntax :

```
    export default ClassName;
```

Alternatively, if you want to export a function , you can do by -

```
   export const functionName = () => (
        // Some other JSX
   );
```

Comment: This is basic stuff to export from the "root level".
The problem being asked is exporting a method from within a component.
Basically, consider your second snippet which would be a functional component. Add methods in there. Now you want to access those from the outside which seems not to be allowed.